# Can a Razor Page be shared between 2 projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages solution with 2 web projects. One is for my internal users and one is external facing. I have a requirement to create a search page that will be used in both projects. In the interest of not duplicating code, I am looking for a way that I can create this page once which will then use a web API for data access. I looked into Razor Class Library but cannot understand if I am able to place my .cshtml and backing .cs file there. If I can, how do I reference this page in another project? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can, how do I reference this page in another project?

Yes, you can follow the below  steps.

**1. Create Razor Class Library:**

You can Right click on the solution in Soultion Explorer and choose `Add » New Project`, and select **Razor Class Library**. Select **Support pages and views** . Then select Create.

[image]

**2.Add a reference to the  Razor Class Library:**

Add a reference to the  Razor Class Library from within the web project. You can do this by right-clicking on `Dependencies` of the web project  and choosing `Add Project Reference`,  looks like this:

[image]

then select then Razor Class Library ,and select ok:
[image]

3.result:

This is Razor Class Library  structure :

[image]
[image]

Both  2 web projects need to add a reference to the  Razor Class Library.